# how to return a scarlar with let as method

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to compare if an array is a subset of other and use it in another query. I could get the comparision method working. However, if I use the compare method in another query I get an error saying "Left and right side of the relational operator must be scalars" This hints that the comparearrays is not reutrning a scalar. Any ideas?

```
let x = parsejson('["a", "b", "c"]');
let y = parsejson('["a", "b", "c"]');
let z = parsejson('["b","a"]');
let comparearrays =  (arr1:dynamic, arr2:dynamic)
{
let arr1Length = arraylength(arr1);
let total =   
range s from 0 to arr1Length-1 step 1    
| project dat = iff(arr1[s] in (arr2), true , false)
| where dat == true 
| count;
total | extend isEqual= iff(Count == arr1Length,'true','false') | project 
tostring(isEqual)

};
//comparearrays(z, x)

datatable (i:int) [4] | project i | where comparearrays(x,y) == 'true'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding - the current implementation returns a table with a single row and single column, but have no fear - `toscalar` to the rescue:

```
let x = parsejson('["a", "b", "c"]');
let y = parsejson('["a", "b", "c"]');
let z = parsejson('["b","a"]');
let comparearrays =  (arr1:dynamic, arr2:dynamic)
{
    let arr1Length = arraylength(arr1);
    let result  =   
        range s from 0 to arr1Length-1 step 1    
        | project dat = iff(arr1[s] in (arr2), true , false)
        | where dat == true 
        | count 
        | extend isEqual = iff(Count == arr1Length,'true','false') 
        | project tostring(isEqual);
    toscalar(result)
};
//comparearrays(z, x)
datatable (i:int) [4] | project i | where comparearrays(x,y) == 'true'
```

You do have a bug in the `comparearrays` functions, since `comparearrays(z, x)` returns true which is not correct....

Comment: Thanks @EranG I see that my question is answered. but there is a technical limitation where I cannot use a method for passing a temperory(just calculated) value from other query. So, I had to write my query inline instead of calling a method.